# Upgrading Telerik Asp.net application still finding the Previous dll

Tags: asp.net, reference, telerik, iis-6

I am facing an issue. I am using Rad Control from Telerik asp.Net Ajax, i have update my web App from Version 2012.2.912.40 to version 2013.1.220.40. it is working fine on local, but when i updated the server it gives me this error.

"Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2012.2.912.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I don't know why it is still pointing to the previous version.

here is the web.Config Handlers

```
<httpHandlers>
      <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*" />
      <add type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" path="*.asmx" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" validate="false" />
      <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

Please Help me Out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you update the server?  You will need to deploy both your updated web project DLL file and copies of the new Telerik.Web.UI.dll as well as the Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll

Comment: Yes I have uploaded all the files except few dll files in which one of the dll is Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll. Aafter uploading this dll it worked.

Thanks Jeff